# Can't get authorization for my Apps Script (Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I keep getting the following error:

Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
at onEdit(Code:10:29)

I read that I need to setup an installable Trigger but every time I try I get this error:

[Something went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdZJS.png)

It's an account managed by my employer, maybe I need to be given certain permissions by the administrator?

I've also tried changing the project to Standard GCP and manually putting the auth there but nothing really happens.

I'm pretty new to all this so forgive me if I'm not being clear enough.